# Difference between supremum and upper bounds and between infimum and lower bounds

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having some difficulties catching the difference between upper bound and supremum and, similarly, between lower bound and infimum.

Let's take a look at this set:

$A=\{x\in \mathbb Q | 0<x\leq\sqrt2\}$

So the supremum is $\sup(A)=\sqrt2$, but I don't think an infimum exists at all so
$\nexists\inf(A)$. Isn't by definition $\sup(A)$ also an upper bound? Are there any other upper bounds? By consequence there aren't any lower bounds, are they?

$B=\{x\in\mathbb Q|x^2\leq4\}$

Do the upper bound and supremum coincide? (Similarly  do the lower bound and infimum coincide?)

$\inf(B)=-2$, $\sup(B)=2$

Comment: Looking over your post, by supremum and upper bound you probably mean the maximum and supremum...

Comment: The number $2$, for instance, is an upper bound. Any number that is greater than or equal to any element of the set is an upper bound.

Comment: Looked it over on Wikipedia, I'm sorry if I can't use the proper terminology, this isn't exactly my field, but I need to study this subject though.

Comment: A supremum is always an upper bound, but not every upper bound is a supremum: the supremum is the *smallest* upper bound. Likewise, the infimum is the *largest* of the lower bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P$ be a (partially) ordered set, and let $A$ be a subset of $P$.

1. We say $x\in P$ is an **upper bound** for $A$ if and only if $a\leq x$ for all $a\in A$.
2. We say $s\in P$ is the **supremum** of $A$ if and only if two things happen:

   - $s$ is an upper bound for $A$; that is, $a\leq s$ for all $a\in A$; **and**
   - $s$ is the *smallest* upper bound for $A$; that is, if $a\leq x$ for all $a\in A$, then $s\leq x$.

The definitions for lower bound and infimum are dual:

1. We say $y\in P$ is a **lower bound** for $A$ if and only if $y\leq a$ for all $a\in A$.
2. We say $t\in P$ is the **infimum** of $A$ if and only if two things happen:

   - $t$ is a lower bound for $A$; that is, $t\leq a$ for all $a\in A$; **and**
   - $t$ is the *largest* lower bound for $A$; that is, if $y\leq a$ for all $a\in A$, then $y\leq t$.

Note that neither the supremum nor the infinmum is required to be *in* $A$. If they are, then they are also called the **maximum** and the **minimum**, respectively. The difference between the supremum and the maximum is that the maximum *must* be in the set, and the supremum does not have to. (In the real numbers, every set that has upper bound *must* have a supremum, but it does not have to have a maximum.)

You should be able to verify that you are correct that $\sqrt{2}$ is the supremum of your set $A$. And that **any** number larger than $\sqrt{2}$ is also an upper bound for $A$.

Note also that $0$ is the infimum of $A$, so you are incorrect in saying that $A$ does not have an infimum.

For $B$, the supremum is $2$, and the infimum is $-2$. Check that.

---

Now, in the case of the real  numbers there are other ways to express the condition of being the smallest upper bound for $A$. It's possible you have seen it defined a different way. Here is a typical one:

**Proposition.** Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then $s$ is the supremum of $A$ if and only if:

- for all $a\in A$, we have $a\leq s$; **and**
- For all $\epsilon\gt 0$, there exists $a\in A$ (which may depend on $\epsilon$) such that $s-\epsilon\lt a\leq s$.

*Proof.* Suppose that $s$ is the supremum of $A$. Then certainly $a\leq s$ for all $a\in A$. Now let $\epsilon\gt 0$. Then, using the contrapositive of the second part of the definition of supremum, we see that since $s-\epsilon\lt s$, then $s-\epsilon$ cannot be an upper bound for $A$, so therefore there exists $a\in A$ such that $s-\epsilon\lt a$. This gives the condition in the proposition.

Conversely, suppose that $s$ satisfies the conditions in the theorem. To show that it is the supremum of $A$, we must show it is the smallest upper bound for $A$. Indeed, it is an upper bound by the first condition.  Now, if $x\lt s$, then there exists $\epsilon\gt 0$ such that $x=s-\epsilon$. By the second condition of the proposition, there exists $a\in A$ such that $x\lt a\leq s$. Thus $x$ is **not** an upper bound for $A$. So we have shown: if $x$ is smaller than $s$, then $x$ is not an upper bound for $A$. The contrapositive of this is: if $x$ is an upper bound for $A$, then $x$ is *not* smaller than $s$ (i.e.,, $s\leq x$). This proves $s$ is the supremum. $\Box$

Answer (score 1):

An upper bound is any element that is larger than everything in the set you're considering. For your set $A$, $3,4$ and $5$ are all upper bounds. The supremum is the least upper bound (which is the name I learned to call it). So $\sup_{x \in A} x = \sup (A)= \sqrt 2$.

There is a similar relationship for lower bounds, infimums, and greatest lower bounds.

Comment: So the upper bound doesn't necessarily has to belong to A, in this case, to be called as such. It can be any element, right? Is it also true for the supremum?

Comment: @haunted85: You are correct - these elements don't have to be included. For example, the inf of $A$ is $0$, even though that's not in $A$. Whether the set contains its bounds is closely related to open-ness and closed-ness sets.