# whats the difference between a set having an upper-bound and it having a supremum?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does it simply depend on if we are in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, and whether the supremum exists in this set? like a set of all $a^2 < 2$ will be upper-bounded in $\mathbb{Q}$, but won't have a supremum, and in $\mathbb{R}$ it will be both upper-bounded and have a supremum?

Does it always work like that and is this the only difference?

Comment: Related: [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166653/difference-between-supremum-and-upper-bounds-and-between-infimum-and-lower-bound)

Comment: Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$. If $A$ is bounded then a supremum of $A$ exists and it is a real number $s:=\sup A$ (by the least upper bound property/axiom of the reals). The supremum $s$ may or may not be in $A$. If we replace $\mathbb{R}$ with the rationals, then $A$ can be bounded, but no least upper bound necessarily exists, as you pointed out with a standard example.